# Is casting to nested struct pointers safe?

Tags: c

Given two structs declared as

```
struct _inner {
    char *inner_value;
};

struct _outer {
    struct _inner common;
    char *outer_value;
};
```

Can I assume that the following cast from a `struct _outer *` to `struct _inner*` will succeed in every compiler?

```
struct _outer *outer_struct;
struct _inner *inner_struct = (struct _inner *)outer_struct;
```

What is the minimum standard version of C, where this cast is guaranteed to succeed?

**EDIT**: I have changed `struct _one` to `struct _inner` in the outer struct.

Comment: `_outer` is not having any `_inner`, so shall we assume it is typedef to `_one`?

Comment: If you redefine `struct _outer { char *outer_value; struct _one common;}` there is no problem, but as is, it's not good.

Comment: Note that while this is guaranteed to work in later versions of the C standard, the addition of this guarantee is an example of codifying existing practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A casting like that is guaranteed to succeed by C99 standard:

> 6.7.2.1-13: A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa. There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.

Comment: Is this also true for structs within structs within structs?

Answer (score -1):

Of course you can cast it. But if you want to be able access to `char *inner_value;` and `char *outer_value;` you need to change order in `_outer`:

```
struct _outer {
    char *outer_value; // <----|
    struct _one common; // <---|
};
```